# function adding object directly; end of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having a problem with this function (it's in JavaScript) i am creating. Running the code gives me a

> Syntax Error: Unexpected Token =

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. I think it's caused at this piece of code:

```
contacts[contacts.length]
```

but I'm not sure, for I was told this is possible? Oh and the `contacts` is an array. What I am trying to do is add the object to the end of the array. Any help will be appreciated, I am quite new with JS. Here is my entire function:

```
function add(firstName, lastName, email, phoneNumber) {
   contacts[contacts.length] = {
      firstName = this.firstName,
      lastName = this.lastName,
      email = this.email,
      phoneNumber = this.phoneNumber
    };
};
add("Ross", "Lynch", "rossShorR5@r5rocks.com", "(650) 222-2222");
list();
```

Comment: Object literals should use `:` to separate keys from values, not `=`

Comment: @thefourtheye Thank You! Feel so stupid now. I sat for hours and I didn't even realize my error.

Answer (score 1):

The list of key/value pairs is comma delimited, with each key and value separated by a colon and `:` to separate keys from values. Continue reading [JavaScript Objects](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)

Your correct code is:

```
function add(firstName, lastName, email, phoneNumber) {
   contacts[contacts.length] = {
      firstName   : this.firstName,
      lastName    : this.lastName,
      email       : this.email,
      phoneNumber : this.phoneNumber
    };
};
add("Ross", "Lynch", "rossShorR5@r5rocks.com", "(650) 222-2222");
list();
```

Comment: @SarjanDesai Why MDM?

Comment: MDN is far more better than w3school

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this using "this" is:

```
functon Contact(firstName, lastName, email, phoneNumber)
{
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}
function addContact(firstName, lastName, email, phoneNumber)
{
    contacts[contacts.length] = new Contact(firstName, lastName, email, phoneNumber);
}
addContact("Ross", "Lynch", "rossShorR5@r5rocks.com", "(650) 222-2222");
```